# What's the meaning of the "as"

Tags: word-usage

> Clooney must've been eager, after helping to shape such acid anti-imperialist movies ***as*** "Syriana" to make a hopeful, positive war picture with a lighthearted marching drum and woodwind score but he plays everything so safe. He doesn't linger on the contrast between timeless masterpieces and the chaos and obscenity of war.

What's the meaning of "as"? Does it mean the movie is just "Syriana"? Or a movie like "Syriana"?

Comment: It's part of "such ... as", *"such [acid anti-imperialist movies] as ["Syriana"]"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that Syriana is the movie, or one of the movies, in question. It does not mean a movie like Syriana (in that case, I would remove 'such' and replace 'as' with 'like'). To rephrase it, it could mean:

- *Shaping acid anti-imperialist movies, such as "Syriana"* - Clooney shaped many acid anti-imperialist movies, and Syriana is one of them; or
- *Shaping "Syriana", an acid anti-imperialist movie* - Clooney shaped Syriana, which is an acid anti-imperialist movie.

I would say that the first is more likely. If "Syriana" is the only example (or the only example being discussed), personally I would say *Shaping **such an** acid anti-imperialist movie **as** "Syriana"* instead, as it is clearer.